# Multiply Matrix and Vector4 XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

How do I multiply a Matrix by a Vector4 in XNA/monogame?

```
        Matrix a = Matrix.Identity;
        Vector4 b = Vector4.Zero;
        b = a*b;
```

This gives an error. This should be allowed afaik. Do I really need to make my own function to multiply a vector by a matrix???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of static `Transform` methods on `Vector4` which are probably what you're looking for. In particular [this one](https://docs.monogame.net/api/Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Vector4.html#Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Vector4_Transform_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Vector4_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_Matrix_).

```
public static Vector4 Transform(Vector4 value, Matrix matrix)
```

```
Matrix a = Matrix.Identity;
Vector4 b = Vector4.Zero;
Vector4 c = Vector4.Transform(b, a);
```

The implementation looks similar to the following (presented in terms of the above variables).

```
c.X = b.X * a.M11 + b.Y * a.M21 + b.Z * a.M31 + b.W * a.M41;
c.Y = b.X * a.M12 + b.Y * a.M22 + b.Z * a.M32 + b.W * a.M42;
c.Z = b.X * a.M13 + b.Y * a.M23 + b.Z * a.M33 + b.W * a.M43;
c.W = b.X * a.M14 + b.Y * a.M24 + b.Z * a.M34 + b.W * a.M44;
```

Comment: is this the same as just multiplying them? like no issues if i had a = sca * rot * pos;

Comment: @GamingGecko I added the implementation; I'm not sure if it does what you want mathematically.

Comment: yep that looks good, baffling why they don't just override the operator but thanks for your help anyway